# Angular2 ElementRef nativeElement check if element is disabled

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this in my directive, named 'bgcolor':

```
export class BgColorDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        console.log(el.nativeElement.disabled); // show "false"
        if (el.nativeElement.disabled) {
            el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#5789D8';
            el.nativeElement.style.color = '#FFFFFF';
        }
    }
```

In my template, I have :

```
<button (click)="submitData()" [disabled]="true" bgcolor [routerLink]="['Onboarding']"> </button>
```

I don't understant why `el.nativeElement.disabled` returns `false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you need to wait for the bindings to be resolved. For example by moving the code of your constructor into the `ngOnInit` hook:

```
export class BgColorDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.disabled); // show "true"
    if (this.el.nativeElement.disabled) {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#5789D8';
        this.el.nativeElement.style.color = '#FFFFFF';
    }
  }
}
```

As a reminder from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html:

> **ngOnInit**: Initialize the directive/component after Angular initializes the data-bound input properties.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `nativeElement` directly, use `Renderer` instead.

```js
export class BgColorDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {

        if (yourCondition) {
            renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'background-color', '#5789D8');
            renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'color', '#FFFFFF');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do the same in the `ngAfterViewInit` method :

```
export class BgColorDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
    ngAfterViewInit():void {
        console.log(this.el.nativeElement.disabled);
        if (this.el.nativeElement.disabled) {
            this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#5789D8';
            this.el.nativeElement.style.color = '#FFFFFF';
        }
    }
}
```